# Hibernate Mapping Classes (Source Class Names)

Tags: hibernate

I want to know how the hibernate reads and binding the values from hbm.xml files. I want to use that kind of functionality in my code. I tried but I was unable to find out that class. So can anyone point me to that class.

Thanx in advnace,
Amar

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but I reckon you mean [java reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/). Hibernate is quite a complex beast, so what you're asking might be all the classes in the core package.

Comment: Thanx Augusto,

I want how they are doing mapping from a java program to a database. I am just asking for a curiosity and just for knowing. How they are doing this mapping. Can you please point me to that place.

Comment: I suggest you download the source code.  It's an open source project.

Comment: It's not just one class but quite a large number of classes working together. If you want to learn the abstract of this, I suggest you to read the book [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://www.bookdepository.co.uk/Patterns-Enterprise-Application-Architecture-Martin-Fowler/9780321127426), in particular the object-relational sections.